# android: do we need to close Db after closing the cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

From source code of SQLiteCursor (stack trace):

```
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbclose(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onAllReferencesReleased(SQLiteDatabase.java:325)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.releaseReference(SQLiteClosable.java:45)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.onAllReferencesReleased(SQLiteProgram.java:119)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.releaseReference(SQLiteClosable.java:45)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.close(SQLiteProgram.java:296)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.close(SQLiteQuery.java:136)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:506)
```

Does it mean that, closing the last cursor will also close the Database. And we dont need to close it explicitly, as in this code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase rdb = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor resultCursor = null;
    String patternQuery = SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(true, "Store", columns, where, null, null, null, null);

    try
    {
        resultCursor = rdb.rawQuery(patternQuery, null);


        resultCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (resultCursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while (!resultCursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                result.add(resultCursor.getString(0));
                resultCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("DB", "Caught an exception while getting pattern based results: " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (resultCursor != null)
        {
            resultCursor.close();
        }
        if (rdb.isOpen())
        {
            rdb.close();
        }
    }
```

so here, we dont need to close the rdb?

note: the cursor object keeps the reference to the database, so it gets a lock on same on each query. Therefore 'SQLiteDatabse.dbclose' effectively closes same database.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to close it.  The database will not be closed until you have explicitly closed it *and* all active cursors have been closed.

Comment: the stack-trace shows that closing cursor also attempts to close the database. in such a scenario, closing DB shouldnt be necessory. Please mention if I am missing some point here.

Comment: I just said what you are missing. :/  You also need to close the database.  It won't be closed at the point you are looking at here if the database wasn't already explicitly closed by you (and is just waiting for all outstanding cursors to be closed before actually shutting down).

Comment: From what I saw, If you try to close the database and then close the cursor, you will get the following exception:  `Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.`. So it won't wait for the cursor.